# Cannot resolve KeyInfo for unwrapping key: KeyInfo 'SecurityKeyIdentifier

Tags: c#-3.0, wcf-binding, wcf-security

I am writing code for `Wcf Client`. My `Wcf` client interacts with `OSB` which requires me to use custom binding and authentication mode as `usernameovertransport`, `OSB` in turn calls a third party vendor.

When I make a request to `OSB` I am getting an encrypted response from the vendor (I can see response using `SOAP UI` and `Fiddler`).

However my wcf client is throwing error,

```
Cannot resolve KeyInfo for unwrapping key: KeyInfo 'SecurityKeyIdentifier
(
IsReadOnly = False,
Count = 1,
Clause[0] = X509SubjectKeyIdentifierClause(SKI = ***Value***)
)
', available tokens 'SecurityTokenResolver
(
TokenCount = 0,
)
'.
```

I tried adding endpoint behavior and mentioning `ClientCredentialType` with the certificate details there but still we are getting the same error.

Any help or guidance on this issue is highly appreciable. Thanks in advance.

**Note:** We own the private key and certificate is installed in the store.

Comment: Did you ever find a fix for this? Having the same problem.